# Matlab: Problem with deleting rows from an array if a certain condition is true

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, dataset

After creating a dataset array (data), I want to delete all rows for which Var4 takes a certain value. Here is what I've done so far:

```
for i=1:length(data.perf)
    if data.Var4(i)==2
        data(i,:)=[]
    end
end
```

The problem of course is that the array gets shorter in every run the condition holds true, so that it stops before all lines are checked. When `i=length(data.perf)` the array is some 50 lines shorter. I think you guys get the problem. Can somebody please suggest me an elegant solution? I will have to do things like this quite often in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you want to loop to `length(data.perf)` and not just `length(data)`? It's not clear from the context but would make more sense...

First suggestion: Reversing your loop could solve the problem of the array getting shorter (`for i = length(data.perf):-1:1`...)

The more elegant solution would be to do it without a for loop

`data(data.Var4==2, :) = [];`

Comment: your second solution is more elegant, indeed. Thanks for the quick reply. I'm still very new to matlab and vector based programming in general.